# Python Django how can't render my variables from views.py on html file

Tags: python, html, css, django

How can i render my variables from models in a html file, they was rendering a time ago before I made html link slug with `class(DetailView)` in my views.py

> HTML FILE (product.html)

```html
<h2 class="heading">{{ product.name }}</h2>
                <div style="clear: both;"><br></div>
                <div class="block">
                  <div class="img_preview">
                    <img src="{{ product.img }}">
                    <div class="categ">
                      {% for category in product.category.all %}
                        <a href=""><span>{{ category }}</span></a>
                      {% endfor %}
                      {# <div style="clear: both"><br></div> #}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="links">
                    {% for link in links %}
                      <div class="download_link">
                        <a href="{{ links.link }}"><span>DOWNLOAD MIRROR NUMBER {{ links.number }}</span></a>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <div id="games">
                    <div id="video_trailer">
                       <iframe  width="560" height="317"   src="{{ product.video_trailer }}" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    <div id="description">
                        <span class="title">Description</span>
                        <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
                       <div id="system_requirements">
                           <span class="title">System Requirements</span><br>
                           <p>Processor:&ensp;{{ product.processor }}<br>
                               <br>
                           Graphic Card:&ensp;{{ product.video }}<br>
                               <br>
                           Memory:&ensp;{{ product.ram }}<br>
                               <br>
                           Disk Space:&ensp;{{ product.disk_space }}<br>
                               <br>
                           OS:&ensp;{{ product.oS }}
                           </p>
                       </div>
                </div>
                <div id="screenshots">
                  {% for image in product_images %}
                   <div class="screenshot">
                     <img  width="1920px" height="1080px" src="{{ image.image }}" >
                   </div>
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
    <aside>
            <div id="news">
                <h2 class="heading">News</h2>
                <div style="clear: both"><br></div>
                {% for articles in news_articles %}
                <div id="articles">
                    <div class="article">
                    <a href="{{ articles.article.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{{ articles.image }}">
                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <span></span><div style="clear: both"></div>
                    </a>
                    <em>{{ articles.article.created }}</em>
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.models import *
from news.models import *
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class GameLink(DetailView):
    # model = Product
    # context_object_name = 'product'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])


class ArticleLink(DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Article, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])

def product(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    product_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=False, id=product_id)
    links = ProductDownload.objects.filter(is_active=True, product=product_id)
    news_articles = NewsImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True)
    return render(request, 'products/product.html', locals())
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import *
from products import views
from products.views import *

urlpatterns = [
   # url(r'^games/(?P<product_id>\w+)/$', views.product, name='product'),
   url(r'^games/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', GameLink.as_view(template_name = 'products/product.html'), name='product'),
   url(r'^articles/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleLink.as_view(template_name = 'news/article.html'), name='article')
]
```

> models.py

`

```html
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(default=None)
    processor = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    disk_space = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    oS = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    video_trailer = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, blank=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, max_length=250, unique=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', args=[str(self.slug)])


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Game'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Games'


class ProductDownload(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=False)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.product.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Download Link'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Download Links'

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.product

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'
```

HTML file show only Product variables that are called with `{{ product.___ }}` but doesn't renders the rest like my links called with :
`{% for link in links %}`
    `{{ link.link }}`
`{% endfor %}`
 or like my articles...

How should I proceed to render on my page needed models.

> Image of file paths
>   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G86NZ.png)

Comment: I'm a full noob in programming, and my english is not very good, so please explain simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different forms to add adicional 'variables' using a DetailView   [(link)](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-to-pass-additional-variables-in-template-when-using-django-generic-views/)

For example:

```
class GameLink(DetailView):

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def links(self):
        return ProductDownload.objects.filter(is_active=True, product=self.object)
```

And in product.html:

```
{% for link in view.links %}
    <div class="download_link">
        <a href="{{ link.link }}"><span>DOWNLOAD MIRROR NUMBER {{ links.number }}</span></a>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

IF you don't want to change HTML, instead of declaring the "def links(self)":

```
class GameLink(DetailView):

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GameLink, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['links'] = ProductDownload.objects.filter(is_active=True, product=self.object)
        return context
```

Comment: I'll use first))

Comment: It works with links and product_images but doesn't work with articles

Comment: It work with `def links` and`def product_images` but don't works with `def articles` :                                                                                                
 `def articles(self):
        return NewsImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True, article=self.object)`

Comment: says `Cannot query "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt": Must be "Article" instance`.

Comment: @YourLogarithm, about the second one: i edited the line "context = super(GameLink, self)" it was with a typo

Comment: I can't see NewsImage on your model